# Angular post request expect a GET

Tags: angular, typescript, http, post, angular6

I have a simple function that cannot be processed, here is the ts code.

```
update(accNode: CcAccNode): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post<CcAccNode>('/api/core_component/acc/' + accNode.accId, {
    'objectClassTerm': accNode.objectClassTerm,
    'state': accNode.state,
    'den': accNode.den,
    'definition': accNode.definition,
    'is_abstract': accNode.abstracted,
    'is_deprecated': accNode.deprecated,
  });
}
```

The logs give me this kind of response :

```
Request URL: http://localhost:4200/api/core_component/acc/8150
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:4200
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

---

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
allow: GET
```

How to bypass that ? Thanks you !

Comment: Could this be a backend problem?, are you sure that the endpoint is for a post method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making a `POST` but your service expects a `GET` request.
You need something like this

```
update(accNode: CcAccNode): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get<CcAccNode>('/api/core_component/acc/' + accNode.accId +
    '?objectClassTerm=' + accNode.objectClassTerm +
    'state=' +  accNode.state +
    'den=' +  accNode.den +
    'definition=' +  accNode.definition +
    'is_abstract=' +  accNode.abstracted +
    'is_deprecated=' +  accNode.deprecated
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not very sure but I believe that you have not added the url correctly. It seems as you are posting to you own front-end server:

```
http://localhost:4200/api/core_component/acc/8150´
```

and I do not know if it is what you want. when you do

```
return this.http.post<CcAccNode>('/api/core_component/acc/' + accNode.accId, {...})
```

perhaps you should replace

```
'/api/core_component/acc/'
```

with

```
yourBackendBaseUrl + '/api/core_component/acc/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your response, there was a SQL typo in the backend, I thought maybe it was located on the front but as Hjbello told me it was a Backend problem !
Thanks again guys !! :)